# Do these concurrent requests cause restful service failure?

Tags: java, rest, executorservice

I am using a Future Callable to concurrently call the following method. And I received an "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL" exception captured by the third catch statement of the following code.

Is there a way to modify this code to make it thread safe? Or this exception occurs simply because multiple concurrent HTTP requests can't be handled by the server (the server is busy), so it rejects some requests and print out the HTTP 502 error code. I think if the server is busy, the processing should slow down and shouldn't throw an exception.

```
private String executeParser(String sku, String inputText, String msgId) {

        String jsonOutput = null;
        String urlStr = null;
        try {
            String encodedInputText = URLEncoder.encode("\"" + inputText + "\"", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
            urlStr = parserServerSelection();
            URL url = new URL(urlStr + encodedInputText);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            jsonOutput = in.readLine();
            in.close();
            LOGGER.info("{} is parsed by {} {}", sku, urlStr, msgId);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("UnsupportedEncodingException failed! {} {} {} {}", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("MalformedURLException failed! {} {} {} {}", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("IOException failed! {} {} {} {}", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonOutput;
    }
```

EDIT:

```
private String parserServerSelection() {
        int numOfParsers = PARSER_WEBSERVICE_URL.size();
        if (numOfParsers == 1) {
            return PARSER_WEBSERVICE_URL.get(0);
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        return PARSER_WEBSERVICE_URL.get(random.nextInt(numOfParsers));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method invoked only uses parameter references, and no shared data, it will be thread safe by definition.

I see no references to `this`, so I'll assume no shared, mutable references.  I can't see what your `parserServerSelection` method is doing.

HTTP 502 means [bad gateway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502).  That does not mean you failed to make the method thread safe.

Your exception handling can be far simpler.  The catch block is repeated four times, except for the duplicate exception name in the message.  I'd collapse those into a single catch:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    String message = String.format("sku: %s inputText: %s URL: %s msgId: %s", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId); 
    LOGGER.error(message, e);
}
```

Comment: I added 'parserServerSelection' which is a method to randomly select a URL string from a list of URLs. This method should be thread safe.

Comment: Creating a new Random in method scope is the wrong thing to do.  You need to make that a class member.  That method will have to be synchronized.  Why do you need a random URL?

Comment: why do you think it's wrong to create a Random in method scope? My use case needs to create random url to use from a pool of urls.